PyCharm can work with setup.py but not pyproject.toml
I have a package my_lib and want to use it in another repo in pycharm.
When I have my setup.py file
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name='my_lib',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='Some author',
    author_email='some@email.com',
    description='',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url='https://github.com/my-proj/my-lib',
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/my-proj/my-lib/issues"
    },
    license='Apache-2.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'fastapi'
    ],
)

I can install it via
pip3.12 install -e ../my-lib
and PyCharm recognizes everything
However, when I add pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=64", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_lib"
version = "1.0.0"
description = ""
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
license = {text = "Apache-2.0"}
authors = [{name = "Some author", email = "some@email.com"}]
dependencies = [
    "fastapi"
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://github.com/my-proj/my-lib"
'Bug Tracker' = "https://github.com/my-proj/my-lib/issues"

the other project does not recognize something like
from my_lib.a import b

anymore.
Do you know how to resolve that?

Same here. Now that we moved to a .toml, when I install my project from a terminal (using pip install -e .), and use this environment as the project's interpreter, pycharm does not find my "modules" (my cython files) anymore.

We changed our project's dependencies to leverage pyproject.toml instead of the setup.py which caused the same issue where the Cython (.pyx) files were not recognized by PyCharm's editor, but everything was built correctly. Every import from a Cython file showed squiggly red lines.
After upgrading from PyCharm Community 2024.3 to PyCharm Professional 2024.3, the squiggly red lines disappeared and the Cython files seemed to integrate properly.
